# Android OOM, memory is never released

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developing on Android 2.3.3 API Lv10. My app uses the 'LoaderManager' interface to load images in the background, and the images are displayed in a ViewPager. If I repeat viewing the images, the app will crash eventually. It looks like the app allocate memory to fast, and the GC is not able to release some of it.

Is there any way to track which object is hold in memory?

```
02-02 18:02:05.564: D/dalvikvm(255): GC_EXPLICIT freed 500K, 55% free 2599K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 534ms
02-02 18:02:05.714: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 365K, 54% free 2680K/5703K, external 3045K/3338K, paused 54ms
02-02 18:02:06.074: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 54% free 2677K/5703K, external 4211K/5259K, paused 62ms
02-02 18:02:10.645: D/dalvikvm(316): GC_EXPLICIT freed 322K, **54% free** 2539K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 100ms
02-02 18:02:53.054: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 109K, **53% free** 2684K/5703K, external 6691K/6808K, paused 48ms
02-02 18:03:16.834: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 604K, 55% free 2720K/5959K, external 8954K/9904K, paused 52ms
02-02 18:03:18.304: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 114K, 55% free 2711K/5959K, external 6160K/6211K, paused 47ms
02-02 18:03:21.534: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 128K, 55% free 2731K/5959K, external 8375K/9165K, paused 38ms
02-02 18:03:29.154: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 612K, 55% free 2757K/6023K, external 10236K/11261K, paused 50ms
02-02 18:03:30.394: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 90K, 55% free 2719K/6023K, external 8070K/8080K, paused 45ms
02-02 18:03:33.944: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 571K, 54% free 2786K/6023K, external 9093K/10112K, paused 74ms
02-02 18:03:36.304: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 115K, 54% free 2777K/6023K, external 7952K/8724K, paused 45ms
02-02 18:03:41.194: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 319K, 53% free 2877K/6023K, external 10954K/10980K, paused 51ms
02-02 18:03:58.054: I/dalvikvm(389): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
02-02 18:03:58.454: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1254K, 58% free 2841K/6727K, external 8152K/8375K, paused 4ms+5ms
02-02 18:04:01.314: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 80K, 58% free 2847K/6727K, external 8078K/8375K, paused 57ms
02-02 18:04:02.244: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 66K, 58% free 2884K/6727K, external 10625K/11366K, paused 40ms
02-02 18:04:07.614: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 191K, 58% free 2874K/6727K, external 13698K/14474K, paused 49ms
02-02 18:04:16.104: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 566K, 57% free 2925K/6727K, external 12504K/12547K, paused 41ms
02-02 18:04:16.574: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 194K, 58% free 2837K/6727K, external 8589K/9589K, paused 51ms
02-02 18:04:18.774: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 71K, 58% free 2862K/6727K, external 9048K/11075K, paused 40ms
02-02 18:04:20.705: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 108K, 58% free 2859K/6727K, external 11804K/12545K, paused 49ms
02-02 18:04:22.475: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 58% free 2861K/6727K, external 14210K/16258K, paused 40ms
02-02 18:04:24.044: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 58% free 2863K/6727K, external 16920K/18968K, paused 47ms
02-02 18:04:24.153: E/dalvikvm-heap(389): 1232160-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-02 18:04:24.255: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 58% free 2863K/6727K, external 16920K/18968K, paused 29ms
02-02 18:04:24.265: W/dalvikvm(389): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-02 18:04:24.565: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 91K, 58% free 2850K/6727K, external 16967K/18968K, paused 149ms
02-02 18:04:25.664: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 58% free 2850K/6727K, external 17021K/18968K, paused 161ms
02-02 18:04:27.144: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 39K, 58% free 2880K/6727K, external 17000K/18968K, paused 49ms
02-02 18:04:27.364: I/dalvikvm-heap(389): Clamp target GC heap from 24.004MB to 24.000MB
02-02 18:04:27.374: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 58% free 2880K/6727K, external 17048K/18968K, paused 29ms
02-02 17:48:09.424: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1400K, 61% free 2686K/6727K, external 3045K/3330K, paused 4ms+4ms
02-02 17:48:10.284: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 58K, 60% free 2707K/6727K, external 2972K/3330K, paused 37ms
02-02 17:48:11.664: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 78K, 60% free 2709K/6727K, external 3842K/4799K, paused 44ms
02-02 17:48:17.364: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 161K, 60% free 2719K/6727K, external 5843K/6032K, paused 41ms
02-02 17:48:25.824: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 157K, 60% free 2726K/6727K, external 8108K/8682K, paused 76ms
02-02 17:48:30.084: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 157K, 60% free 2732K/6727K, external 10488K/11355K, paused 63ms
02-02 17:48:39.704: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_CONCURRENT freed 742K, 58% free 2888K/6727K, external 12840K/13865K, paused 4ms+3ms
02-02 17:48:43.895: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 893K, 60% free 2749K/6727K, external 3941K/4896K, paused 52ms
02-02 17:48:58.414: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 160K, 60% free 2750K/6727K, external 6400K/6445K, paused 55ms
02-02 17:49:02.324: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 375K, 59% free 2821K/6727K, external 9503K/9541K, paused 43ms
02-02 17:49:03.755: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 320K, 59% free 2777K/6727K, external 4944K/5945K, paused 69ms
02-02 17:49:08.184: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 212K, 59% free 2767K/6727K, external 7593K/7630K, paused 46ms
02-02 17:49:10.914: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 451K, 59% free 2805K/6727K, external 5893K/6353K, paused 50ms
02-02 17:49:15.294: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 163K, 58% free 2843K/6727K, external 9263K/9265K, paused 39ms
02-02 17:49:16.434: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 499K, 58% free 2835K/6727K, external 6842K/7538K, paused 76ms
02-02 17:49:18.824: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 109K, 58% free 2831K/6727K, external 9008K/9765K, paused 43ms
02-02 17:49:25.774: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 645K, 59% free 2816K/6727K, external 12225K/12235K, paused 53ms
02-02 17:49:35.494: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 60K, 58% free 2864K/6727K, external 10256K/12304K, paused 54ms
02-02 17:49:59.824: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1593K, 60% free 2905K/7111K, external 13747K/14632K, paused 58ms
02-02 17:50:02.764: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 114K, 59% free 2927K/7111K, external 11181K/12092K, paused 73ms
02-02 17:50:04.605: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 151K, 59% free 2935K/7111K, external 13655K/14466K, paused 47ms
02-02 17:50:09.174: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 513K, 59% free 2970K/7111K, external 15783K/15803K, paused 49ms
02-02 17:50:14.434: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 247K, 59% free 2926K/7111K, external 11360K/11714K, paused 52ms
02-02 17:50:20.464: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 608K, 59% free 2960K/7111K, external 13909K/14934K, paused 50ms
02-02 17:50:24.415: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 143K, 59% free 2980K/7111K, external 14651K/15393K, paused 43ms
02-02 17:50:24.655: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 59% free 2980K/7111K, external 14651K/15393K, paused 49ms
02-02 17:50:24.725: I/dalvikvm-heap(337): Clamp target GC heap from 24.113MB to 24.000MB
02-02 17:50:24.725: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 59% free 2980K/7111K, external 17058K/19106K, paused 59ms
02-02 17:50:24.805: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 59% free 2980K/7111K, external 17058K/19106K, paused 69ms
02-02 17:50:25.045: E/dalvikvm-heap(337): 2774400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-02 17:50:25.115: I/dalvikvm-heap(337): Clamp target GC heap from 24.112MB to 24.000MB
02-02 17:50:25.115: D/dalvikvm(337): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 59% free 2980K/7111K, external 17058K/19106K, paused 56ms
02-02 17:50:25.304: E/GraphicsJNI(337): VM won't let us allocate 2774400 bytes
```

Comment: paste your LoaderManager class here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links given by @JoxTraex are great. But to this issue, I finally found the root cause. It is the **LoaderManager** which holds a reference to the Loader object and the object returned by the **Loader.loadInBackground** method. After calling the LoaderManager.destroyLoader(*id*), the problem is gone forever.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a topic that is kind of hard to tackle, specifically if you keep a reference to your Bitmaps, then you start overloading memory. This is because images are VERY heavy in terms of memory/VM. You should have a look at what Romain Guy says about graphics and Bitmaps and how to handle it.

Here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJYTBjMZJh0

They are lengthy videos, but have lots of good information and some of this includes how to handle this with best practices.